# Are nonsense words useful for learning to read?

Tags: phonetics, reading

In my son's 1st grade class they use [nonsense words](http://www.speech-language-development.com/nonsense-words.html) to assess "phonemic awareness". I can understand why that is useful for assessment: for words the child knows, it nullifies the possibility of recognizing it before deciding on whether a potential pronunciation is right or not. But it's not clear to me that it's useful for actually learning to read. Because what is the point of being able to correctly pronounce a word if the reader doesn't know what it means? I would even further argue there is technically no correct pronunciation for a nonsense word but that's less important.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right venue for the question, but: well-structured assessments allow teachers to understand which students need support and/or intervention in particular areas. As an analogy, the final exam is not how you "actually learn". NWF is empirically supported to assess skills necessary for reading. You may find this article, and other literature interesting: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/299136245_Using_Nonsense_Word_Fluency_to_Predict_Reading_Proficiency_in_Kindergarten_Through_Second_Grade_for_English_Learners_and_Native_English_Speakers

Comment: Your son's first grade curriculum has been designed by an expert and is taught by a professionally qualified teacher. I fail to see how a random bunch of people on the internet are going to give you a better answer. If you are unclear what the benefit of this is, you also have access to a professional qualified in early childhood education - i.e. your teacher. I suggest you ask them.

Comment: This is not on topic for ELL, as first grade students are not English Langauge Learners in the sense that applies here, they are not learning in the intellectual way that an adult learner learns a language.

Comment: Interesting that this was closed as opinion based when Katy's comment showed how it can be answered objectively - i.e. empirically - (disregarding my subject line's inadvertent implication that NWF was actually being used to teach rather than just to assess). Off topic it is, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to reframe your question, because as it is written you will only get opinion-based answers, and that is off-topic for the site. But reframed, there is a good question lurking under there. Rather than ask "are they useful", I'm just going to comment on their use, and offer some evidence in support of them.

One of the most widely celebrated authors of children's books, Dr Seuss, used a **lot** of 'nonsense words' in his works. His books have been used by teachers for decades, and the author was even awarded an honourary doctorate of human letters for his contribution to literature. Clearly, the use of 'nonsense words' in his works is not considered by these educators to hamper the progress of new readers.

One issue around nonsense words is that there may be no reliable source to check pronunciation. Seuss's works were often in rhyme, which would act as a guide to the rhyming nonsense words, so long as you recognised the rhyme scheme. But reading words that are completely unfamiliar to us is something that all readers of any age must be prepared for. New nouns - for example, names that may have origins in other languages - may require us to rely on our understanding of English pronunciation. Fictional books for adult readers often contain fictional place names for which there is no reliable pronunciation guide such as a dictionary. The science fiction genre in particular is full of names of fictional races and proper nouns which the author has created.

So, while it may be a matter of opinion whether reading these kinds of words is 'useful' in learning to read or not, there is clearly support from some educators, and reasons to believe that the effort made in attempting to read such words and the skills it can develop is good practice that could help normal reading.

Comment: Thanks, my question wording was definitely flawed. It implied that NWF is being used to teach reading when it's actually only used to assess students' phonemic skills. Technically both are probably answerable with objective data (as Katy's linked paper demonstrates), but I'm not actually aware of NWF being used formally to teach reading.

Comment: The motivation for the question was that I feel assessing on a list of NWF words treats kids a bit like a science experiment (because using NWF controls for their vocabulary knowledge). Maybe I should actually ask my son if he even notes a difference between NWF and the other assessments. ;) Your Dr. Seuss mention inspired me to think of an alternative where (random-ish) nonsense words are introduced into ordinary sentences. That would be neat and possibly more interesting for the kids as well.